# Installing php5-cURL on Backtrack leads to dependencies issues

Tags: apt, backtrack

I am trying to install a program called Glype on my computer for a proxy. I am using Backtrack 5 R3 and I have the latest version of Apache running on it. The problem I have is that Glype needs cURL to run and when I try to install cURL using: "apt-get install php5-curl" it displays an error. It says-

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  php5-curl: Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9) but 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17 is to be installed
```

So is there a way that I can install it without having any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Backtrack's repositories are no longer maintained (in fact, they are packages from Ubuntu 11.10 version), so it's no wonder you have dependencies issues.

The best solution is changing from BackTrack to [Kali Linux](http://kali.org), which is the now maintained distribution. In this you can corroborate that all packages are available and updated from Debian stable repositories:

```
$ apt-cache show php5-curl
Package: php5-curl
Source: php5
Version: 5.4.4-14+deb7u2
Installed-Size: 112
Maintainer: Debian PHP Maintainers 
Architecture: i386
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2), phpapi-20100525+lfs, php5-common (= 5.4.4-14+deb7u2), ucf
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2~)
$ apt-cache policy php5-curl
php5-curl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.5.1+dfsg-2
  Version table:
     5.4.4-14+deb7u2 0
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali/ kali/main i386 Packages
$ apt-cache policy php5-common
php5-common:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.5.1+dfsg-2
  Version table:
     5.4.4-14+deb7u2 0
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali/ kali/main i386 Packages
```

As you notice, Kali repositories has no dependencies problems with this.